# What happens to GraphServiceClient when access token expires?

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

This is the code. I get an access token and with that access token I create a client. What happens if access token expires? Do I need to create another client?. Create only one client? or each time I need users for example, I should call GetGraphServiceClient()? that will resolve the fact that the token is expired because calls for a new one. If not how can I verify if the token is expired?

```
public async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClient()
{
    var token = await GetAccessToken();

    var client = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));

    return client;
}

    private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_connectionData.ClientId)
       .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, _connectionData.TenantId)
       .WithClientSecret(_connectionData.ClientSecret)
       .Build();

        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
            .ExecuteAsync();               
        }
        catch (MsalServiceException ex)
        {
            // Case when ex.Message contains: invalid scope
        }

        return result?.AccessToken;
    }
```

Comment: @romil-kumar-jain Could you provide more code? How do you get access token?

Comment: You can assume that you have the latest refresh Token and access token all the time. so no need to go into logic how we are getting this.
That's a long code.

Comment: There's a very similar problem here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007753/using-graphserviceclient-to-get-refresh-tokens-when-authenticating-using-userpas

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are authenticating according to the Graph SDK or the Graph REST API. If you are authenticating against the SDK, as one of the commenters already mentioned, the SDK will take care of that for you as long as you set it up properly. If you are using the REST API, then you will have to take care of it yourself.

SDK Authentication:

GraphSDK.cs

```
public class GraphSDK
{
    public static GraphServiceClient Initialize(IConfiguration config)
    {
        return new GraphServiceClient
            (
                new ClientSecretCredential
                (
                    config.GetValue<string>("TenantID"),
                    config.GetValue<string>("ClientID"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENT_SECRET"),
                    new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud }
                ),
                new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }
            );
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddScoped(svc => GraphSDK.Initialize(Configuration));
        ...
    }
}
```