# Token management for ClientSecretCredential usage in MSGraph API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

I need to send mails from a background application(worker service/azure function) using MSGraph API with Application permission. This is how I have initialized the GraphServiceClient to send emails.

```
var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(
                "TenantID",
                "ClientId",
                "ClientSecret",
                new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });
                
                
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);

var subject = $"Subject from demo code";
var body = $"Body from demo code";

// Define a simple e-mail message.
var email = new Microsoft.Graph.Message
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = body
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = "EmailId" }}
    }
};

// Send mail as the given user. 
graphServiceClient
    .Users["UserID"]
    .SendMail(email, true)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync().Wait();
```

How long the graphServiceClient will have a valid token and how to regenerate a token when the token is expired.

What are the best practices for this usage

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44018281/7687666)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I need something which is compatible with .NET core also this approach sends a username and password to authenticate what I am looking for is to authenticate using a client secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of May 2022, there is no option to generate a refresh token while using client_credentials options.

[For client_credentials option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

It's possible to generate a refresh token while using on behalf of user

[For on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The default lifetime of an access token is variable. When issued, an access token's default lifetime is assigned a random value ranging between 60-90 minutes (75 minutes on average). Please refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#access-token-lifetime.) for more information.

The refresh tokens can be used to acquire access tokens if they expire, Refresh tokens are long-lived, and can be used to retain access to resources for extended periods of time.

For getting the access tokens with client secret please refer this method of getting the [access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token).

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is not applicable for ClientSecretCredential option